# Omnifaces 2.0 error at startup with OpenWebbeans

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, omnifaces, openwebbeans

I'm converting my existing JSF application with Primefaces on TomCat7 to be using CDI and Omnifaces 2.0. I already used a previous version of Omnifaces in the webapp before.

TomEE is not an option and after multiple tries with Weld, I got started with OpenWebbeans. However I receive an error at server startup.
Any help on this?

My configuration (JSF 2.2.8):

**pom.xml**
*Note:* Adding openwebbeans-jsf did not solve anything

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>openwebbeans-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>openwebbeans-tomcat7</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**context.xml**

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.apache.webbeans.container.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
apr 25, 2015 4:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

apr 25, 2015 4:50:34 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/admin'
apr 25, 2015 4:50:34 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
apr 25, 2015 4:50:35 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4990)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:417)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:248)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:488)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:287)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.getReference(BeanManager.java:154)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:69)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:88)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:415)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.getReference(BeanManager.java:143)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to call getBeans(Type, Annotation...) before AfterBeanDiscovery
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectableBeanManager.checkAfterBeanDiscoveryProcessed(InjectableBeanManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectableBeanManager.getBeans(InjectableBeanManager.java:121)
    ... 33 more
```

**[EDIT]**
I followed the blog on the installation of Weld. I added SP1 from Weld before, but I retried now with Final version to catch the necessary traces.
Just adding the weld-servlet dependency gives me the following stacktrace:

```
25 apr 2015 21:37:10  INFO servletWeldServlet - WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
25 apr 2015 21:37:11  INFO Version - WELD-000900: 2.2.10 (Final)
25 apr 2015 21:37:11  INFO Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
25 apr 2015 21:37:13  INFO Bootstrap - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
25 apr 2015 21:37:14  WARN Interceptor - WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
25 apr 2015 21:37:14  WARN Interceptor - WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
25 apr 2015 21:37:15  WARN Event - WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
apr 25, 2015 9:37:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.hasNoArgsConstructor()Z
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.checkForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer.addClasses(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:203)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:372)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.hasNoArgsConstructor()Z
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexClassFileInfo.<init>(JandexClassFileInfo.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexClassFileServices.getClassFileInfo(JandexClassFileServices.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:97)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    ... 4 more
```

I had this error before, I had to add Jandex to the classpath, version 1.2.4.Final

With this library added it seems (and seemed) like the server and application is starting correctly, but it isn't. I never get the "application started" message.
I'm running TomCat through Eclipse localhost on a Windows 7, also tried on Mac but same behaviour. Eclipse never stops showing the message "Starting Tomcat v7.0 ...".
Looking at the threaddump doesn't learn me anything more:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin>jstack -l 4476
2015-04-25 22:11:41
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode):

"Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x4e5dd000 nid=0x126c waiting on condition [0x5013f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x1bc5aed0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x4f205400 nid=0x119c in Object.wait() [0x4e48f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x1bbe5af8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x1bbe5af8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"weld-worker-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x4eb2f800 nid=0x11bc waiting on condition [0x4ed9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x1b5a8570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "localhost-startStop-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x4e1b2400 nid=0xb18 runnable [0x03dce000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:84)
        at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:54)
        at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:144)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:415)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:248)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:488)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:287)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4990)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
        - locked <0x1953f410> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x1953f410> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x0601e4e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync)
        - <0x195beea8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Catalina-startStop-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x4e1b1c00 nid=0x4c4 waiting on condition [0x4e4ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x195e0380> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        - locked <0x1951a790> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        - locked <0x1951a790> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x1951a790> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x195bf000> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=2 tid=0x4e15bc00 nid=0xc90 in Object.wait() [0x4e42f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x19570e38> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
        at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x19570e38> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00dcc800 nid=0x7e0 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00dbf000 nid=0x1248 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00dbdc00 nid=0x7b0 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0070e400 nid=0x980 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x00d93c00 nid=0x11c0 in Object.wait() [0x007ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x193c2cc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x193c2cc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0070c800 nid=0x1618 in Object.wait() [0x00d8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x193c2d50> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x193c2d50> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00614800 nid=0x50c waiting on condition [0x0055f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x195bef98> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        - locked <0x194dbaf8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        - locked <0x194dbaf8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x194dbaf8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        - locked <0x194dbaf8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x194c6188> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        - locked <0x19542560> (a [Lorg.apache.catalina.Service;)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x19434bd0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00709000 nid=0x160c runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00de7400 nid=0x1460 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 221
```

Comment: Strange. It looks like that JSF application is being initialized before CDI application. It works just fine in TomEE. What problem exactly did you have with Weld? Did you follow http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html (with only [this Maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet/2.2.10.Final))

Comment: @BalusC I edited my post with the investigations I did on Weld.

Answer (score 0):

That's non portable behaviour in Omnifaces. Bauke needs to work on this code. 
The CDI spec says nothing about the CDI container having to be available in ServletContainerInitializer. So it is simply not guaranteed in a portable way. It will also not work on Google App Engine, jetty, etc...

I would simply remove that check code from Omnifaces and your application will 'just work' (tm). It's really a false positive...